# When a method exits, does the Timer object in that method exists?

Tags: java, swing, object, reference, stack

I'm reading Java Core recently. Here is the code from section 6.4.5 of Java Core Volume I:

```
public void start(int interval,boolean beep){
    class TimePrinter implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            System.out.println("At the tone,the time is " + new Date());
            if(beep){
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
    ActionListener listener=new TimePrinter();
    Timer t=new Timer(interval,listener);
    t.start();
}
```

What I don't understand are two points:

First, the book says **The `listener` reference is passed to the `javax.swing.Timer` constructor, the timer is started, and the `start()` method exits. At this point,the beep parameter variable of the start method no longer exists.**
Why the `beep` parameter will disappear?

Second, when `start(interval,beep)` method exits, does the `Timer` object(namely,t) exist?
Thanks very much!

Comment: The `beep` parameter is a stack allocated variable. When the method returns, the stack frame that contained it has been removed (repurposed for other method invocations). In that sense, the parameter no longer exists. However, it was copied into the local class instance you created, so its value persists in a field of the instance.

The `Timer` instance creates a `Thread` and starts a thread that internally has a reference to the `Timer` object, so it still exists, yes.

Comment: The questions you had asked are already answered quite a few times - one has to look for specifics. Answering is not easy or a simple. Here are some things specific you can look for: What is a "local" or "method" variable (the `beep` variable is a primitive local variable)? What is stack and heap memory in Java? What happens to objects defined within a method (`Timer` class object `t` - this is a local reference variable)? What is "Garbage Collection" in Java?

Comment: I got it! The rub is that I'm not familiar with Timer class.